# Is it possible to change color text or background of label Y-Axis of Range bar chart

Tags: c#, winforms, mschart

If so please help me how to change that color
[image]

Comment: Such controls are always a challenge to find the proper "hierarchy" under which you must descend to find the desired property. I could have sworn we could set the background, but I just spent half an hours going through different docs, and you'll have to be content with the ForeColor as explained by @tontonsevilla

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change the color of the X-Axis Label:

```
chart2.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelStyle.ForeColor = Color.Yellow;
```

To change the color of the Y-Axis Label:

```
 chart2.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.LabelStyle.ForeColor = Color.Blue;
```

[image: Default:]

[image: Color Change]

Hope it helps. Happy coding.

Comment: Can you set Yellow color for "Suresh" and Red Color for "Ankit" ?

Comment: I think you can't change individual color for each label but you can change the color of the graph for each label.

point = chart2.Series["Salary"].Points.AddXY("Suresh", "8500");
chart2.Series["Salary"].Points[point].Color = Color.Yellow;